# comparing values from a list and a form php

Tags: php, forms, max, text-files, filtering

I have a list on php that is generated from a text file.
And i have some problems filtering the information by a maximum value.
Here is my code:

```
<?php 
            $searchReq = $_POST['searchMaximum'];
            $intValForm = filter_var($searchReq, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

            $f = fopen("info.txt", "r");
            while (($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE) {
                if (strstr($line, $searchReq)) {
                    list( $hPostcode, $hPrice, $hImage, $hViews ) = explode( ",", $line );
                    $intValFile = filter_var($hPrice, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
                    if($intValFile <= $intValForm){    
                        print "<hr/>";
                        print 'Postcode:' . $hPostcode . '<br />';
                        print 'Price: £' .$hPrice . ",000" . '<br />';
                        print "<img src=\"$hImage\" />";
                        print 'Views:' . $hViews . '<br />';
                        print '<br/>';
                    }   
                }

            }
           fclose($f); 
        ?>
```

so it divides the four fields in each line and makes a variable out of each of the fields.
My problem is how to compare the value that i get fom the search box and only the page to show the lines(print the fields) which corresponding variable is below the one searched for.
Can someone help me with this please?
I would really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function filter_var return false, if the filter fails. So you should check the filter result before compare values. The second problem is function strstr, which is used to compare strings, so if you want find row with price 9, and you get from post value 10 - funciton strstr return false. You can try this:

```
$searchReq = $_POST['searchMaximum'];
$intValForm = filter_var($searchReq, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if ($intValForm === false) {
  die('search maximum is not a number');
}

$f = fopen("info.txt", "r");
while (($line = fgets($f)) !== FALSE) {
    list( $hPostcode, $hPrice, $hImage, $hViews ) = explode( ",", $line );
    $intValFile = filter_var($hPrice, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    //omit not valid rows
    if ($intValFile === false) {
      continue;
    }
    if($intValFile <= $intValForm){    
      print "<hr/>";
      print 'Postcode:' . $hPostcode . '<br />';
      print 'Price: £' .$hPrice . ",000" . '<br />';
      print "<img src=\"$hImage\" />";
      print 'Views:' . $hViews . '<br />';
      print '<br/>';
    }   
}
fclose($f);
```